# Navigation Drawer Header how to put name and profile pic image from Google Sign in

Tags: android, firebase, navigation-drawer, firebase-authentication

I was able to make a navigation drawer and google sign in app using firebase tutorials from youtube https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGCjwl1RrtcR1j6EmpBxJyJYowK2QIsdT

I have **activity_navigation.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="rjbc.cpvc.NavigationActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout = "@layout/navigation_action"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="101dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="201dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView5" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>    

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity = "start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and **navigation_header.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/pName">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/pPic"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**this is my navigation_activity.java**

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private TextView mName;

    private String name;
    private Uri photoUrl;
    private ImageView mPic;

    private NavigationView mNavigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(NavigationActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        };

        mName = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mPic = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.pPic);
        getCurrentinfo();

        mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {

                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.nav_account:
                        Toast.makeText(NavigationActivity.this, "Account Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        Toast.makeText(NavigationActivity.this, "Setting Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void getCurrentinfo() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
                // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
                String providerId = profile.getProviderId();

                // UID specific to the provider
                String uid = profile.getUid();

                // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
                name = profile.getDisplayName();
                photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
                mName.setText(name);

                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(photoUrl.toString())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                        .resize(100, 100)
                        .transform(new CircleTransform())
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(mPic);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in my `getcurrentInfo` function I am able to place my name and profile pic in the `activity_navigation.xml` but I want to place it an `navigation_header.xml`

I tried changing the id of my `ImageView` and `TextView` to match with that in the `navigation_header` but my app crashes.

Answer (score 4):

Try this after `mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);`

```
TextView userName = (TextView)mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.username);
```

> It is because you are initializing the textview before the navigationview
>   get initialized

```
mName   = (TextView)mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mPic = (ImageView) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.pPic);
        getCurrentinfo();

        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view); //navigation view is initialized here
```

Comment: Then please mark it as answer it will be glad to others if you marked it who are seeking the same one @Dr.DOOM

Answer (score 4):

This is going to work 100% hopefully.
Let me know if it works.

`

```
    //Initializing firebase objects

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

   //Go to your specific database directory or Child
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

   //Connect the views of navigation bar
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mName   = (TextView)mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textViewHeaderTitle);
    mID   = (TextView)mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textViewHeaderSID);
    mImageView = (CircleImageView) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeaderIcon);

    //Use you DB reference object and add this method to access realtime data
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           //Fetch values from you database child and set it to the specific view object.
            mName.setText(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString()); 
            mID.setText(dataSnapshot.child("sid").getValue().toString());  

            String link =dataSnapshot.child("profile_picture").getValue().toString();
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(link).into(mImageView);   
        }

        //SIMPLE BRO. HAVE FUN IN ANDROID <3 GOOD LUCK

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

`

Comment: had a problem and this worked, but just for clarification, the `getHeaderViews`, it gets the views in the header of a nav drawer.. but how are they are in the same index?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I don't know that part as well XD, I just took that part from the guy who asked this question. It was like his problem was what I already solved.
But my problem was what he already solved. ha ha..
I was also unable to access the navigation drawer but I knew how to get images and text and set them.
Let me know if you find out the reason. that would be a great help bro.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the `getHeaderViews`, gets the views that are defined in the header navigation drawer, and you use `mNavigationView.findViewByid` since the textview is a child of the navigationview. For the index, its 0 since its defined in layout

Answer (score 3):

From NavigationView you will access the textview and imageview with "navigationView.getHeaderView(0)" this line

For Quick Sample

```
TextView userName = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.username);
    userName.setText(new UserPreference().getUser(MainActivity.this).userName);
```

All the Best!!

Comment: Can you try to update your code, so i will look at it